# React Native + NativeBase +Exponent, Element type is invalid error

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am fairly new to react native, nativebase, and Exponent. Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting simple components even to display. I've spent probably 6+ hours troubleshooting simple tutorial components from the nativebase documentation. I feel like I'm just missing something fundamental and I would really appreciate a helping hand.

Here's what I'm doing:
Using Exponent XDE to run my project.
Installed nativebase according to the documentation, no errors at this point.

main.js

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import { CardImageExample } from './component/card.js';



AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => CardImageExample);
```

card.js

```
import React, { Component, Image } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';

class CardImageExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Card>
                        <CardItem>
                            <Thumbnail source={require('./img/penguin-icon.png')} />
                            <Text>Instrumental Songs</Text>
                            <Text note>Guitar</Text>
                        </CardItem>

                        <CardItem>                        
                            <Image style={{ resizeMode: 'cover' }} source={require('./img/penguin.jpg')} /> 
                        </CardItem>

                        <CardItem>
                            <Icon name='ios-musical-notes' style={{color : '#ED4A6A'}} />
                            <Text>Listen now</Text>                        
                        </CardItem>
                   </Card>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
export default CardImageExample;
```

Current error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I just have absolutely no idea where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main.js should like some thing Like

```
import * as Exponent from 'exponent';
import React from 'react';
import First from './src/app';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Button, Left, Right, Body,Icon, Separator } from 'native-base';

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return <First / > ;
 }
}
Exponent.registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your app like this `Exponent.registerRootComponent(App)`.
If you are using Exponent.
Example: https://github.com/exponent/nativebase-example